# England Pre-Grade 1 Piano Theory Help: What does G7 above the stave mean?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, sheet-music

this is a piece I’m playing. The reason it’s so simple is I’ve just started playing piano, but I’m grade 7 for saxophone and Grade 5 in theory, so please correct me on and ask me anything.
In bar 2, by my index finger, there is a C. This, I assume, stands for the C major chord in the first inversion. By my middle finger is a G7. I know the G Major chord is G B D, so why is there a 7 next to the G above the stave and why is the chord made of the letters B F G when that’s not any inversion of G major chord? Btw, I live in Britain.[image]

Comment: B at the bottom is the 3rd of the chord (it's an inversion). F is the (flattened) 7th of the chord and G is the tonic. D is omitted.  F is flattened because we are in the key of C, not the key of G.  G would require F#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When playing a dominant 7th chord on the piano, it is permitted to remove the perfect fifth. In this case the D (perfect 5th) has been removed and the B has been inverted.
It looks like you are using an Alfred book, if you go back a bit you’ll find a section on Primary Chords in C Major.

Comment: In fact, about three inches above the song in question...

Comment: The fifth hasn't been omitted here: it's in the right hand.

Answer (score 0):

A G7 chord contains the notes G, B, D, and (the minor 7th) F. Those two bars, including the melody, contain those notes in the first inversion. The seventh in a dominant seventh chord is minor.
Here's an introduction to [chord symbols](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/what-does-bb7-mean-above-the-stave?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the two systems above the song: *primary chords in C major* and *broken chords*.

G7 is a tetrad, a chord built by  3 thirds: gbdf. The fifth (d) can be omitted.

Look up *dominant 7 chords.*